# left associate an operation in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to return the left association of an expression given (haskell), so if we have a + (b + c) the function has to return (a + b) + c, this also applies for the multiplication since these 2 operations are associative. taking onto consideration the other operations that are not associative therefor I have to put a condition to not left associate those expressions.
so the leftAssociate function turns every expression given into an equivalent left-associated one with the same constants

the function is defined as follow :

```
data Expr = Val Int | App Op Expr Expr

leftAssociate :: Expr -> Expr
leftAssociate (App Add (Val a) (App Add (Val b) (Val c))) = App Add (App Add (Val a) (Val b)) (Val c)
```

I have tried pattern matching but it's too overwhelming as there is a lot of possibilities and also I cannot specify the number of operations given as input as it's not limited.

Comment: Show your current attempt and the definition for `Expr`.

Comment: Start simple. Try to left balance an expression with 3 operands. Then try one with 4. See if that helps you find a pattern to create the general solution. Also start with an expression that only contains one operator, such as addition. Then later figure out how to do a different operator and expressions with mixed operators.

Comment: Your definition of balanced isn't entirely clear.

Comment: data Expr = Val Int | App Op Expr Expr

Comment: so leftbalance is a function that  turns every input into an equivalent left-balanced one with the given constants.

Comment: It's the term "left-balanced" that you haven't defined. Is `(a + b) + (c + d)` left-balanced? Why or why not? What about `(a + b) + c + d`? `((a + b) + c) + d`? `(((a + b) + c) + d)`? (All three of which are equivalent given that `+` is left-associative, but I wouldn't consider them "balanced" in the usual sense of that word.)

Comment: so basically I want it to start having parentheses from the right going to the left so ( a + b) + (c + d) is not left-balanced, also (a + b) + c + d is not balanced but a +( b +(c +d)) is left-balanced

Comment: This seems like a simple function to write *if* you have a proper definition for what it means to be left-balanced.

Comment: So if I were to draw this as a tree, with each node being either a `+` or a constant, then a left-balanced tree is one where every `+` node would have a constant node as its left child? (And every such tree could be written as a left-balanced expression, even if adding the parentheses make no difference to how the expression is evaluated?)

Comment: let's say we have an expression as an input, we consider it left-balances if it has no subexpressions of shape App Op x ( App Op y z) and that's only when the operation is Addition or Multiplication.

Comment: Ok. So to start, there are only three cases to consider: `leftbalance (Val x) = ...`, `leftbalance (App Add x y) = ...`, and `leftbalance (App Mul x y) = ...`. Further, if you can *recursively* balance the two sides of an `App` node, then you just need to combine the results into a new `App` node that is also left-balanced.

Comment: I think you want the term left *associated*. I'll edit your question under the optimistic assumption I'm correct, but feel free to roll back if I've misunderstood. It also looks like your example is backwards compared to your definition and your code, which I will likewise fix for you.

Comment: if I do left balance (App Add x y ) and I recursively balance the two sides it will only work on certain expressions, if an expression has a combination of Add and Sub then it will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

You say

> we consider it left-balances [sic] if it has no subexpressions of shape App Op x ( App Op y z) and that's only when the operation is Addition or Multiplication

I therefore propose that you structure your function for fixing this defect in the way you described:

```
leftAssociate (App Add x (App Add y z)) = -- ...
leftAssociate (App Mul x (App Mul y z)) = -- ...
leftAssociate (App op x y) = -- ...
leftAssociate (Val n) = -- ...
```

Presumably in the first three cases you will make recursive calls at some point to make sure that the `x`, `y`, and `z` subterms are also left-associated. This recursion will be the mechanism that allows you to handle arbitrarily large expressions.

Comment: well I was thinking about that but couldn't figure out a way to call the function recursively

Comment: `y` and `z` are values of type `Expr`; you just call `leftAssociate` on each of them. The trick, though, is what to do with the *results* of those calls. You'll have something like `let y' = leftAssociate y; z' = leftAssociate z'; in ...`, where `...` will have to construct a new value of type `Expr` using `y'` and `z'`.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easiest to conceptualize this like so:  for each subtree rooted at an `App op _ _` node with an `op` you want to re-associate, you can collect all the terms at the top of the subtree being combined with that same `App op` into a flattened list, and then create a left associated tree with a `foldl1` from that list.  This gives the following solution:

```
data Expr = Val Int | App Op Expr Expr deriving (Show)
data Op = Add | Mul | Sub deriving (Show, Eq)

-- Identify which operators should be re-associated
isAssoc :: Op -> Bool
isAssoc Add = True
isAssoc Mul = True
isAssoc _ = False

leftAssociate :: Expr -> Expr
leftAssociate a@(App op _ _)
  | isAssoc op = foldl1 (App op) $ opTerms a
    where opTerms :: Expr -> [Expr]
          opTerms (App op' x' y') | op' == op = opTerms x' ++ opTerms y'
          opTerms e                           = [leftAssociate e]
leftAssociate (App op x y) = App op (leftAssociate x) (leftAssociate y)
leftAssociate e = e
```

You can technically get rid of the intermediate flattened list by constructing the left associated tree directly and defining a concatenation function for left associated trees, and I think that would give you the sort of direct recursive solution being discussed in the other answer, but I found this version easier to write.

Here's a test case:

```
mul = App Mul
add = App Add
sub = App Sub
ex1 = leftAssociate (add (Val 1) (sub (mul (Val 2) (mul (Val 3) (Val 4)))
                                      (add (add (Val 5) (Val 6)) (add (Val 7) (Val 8)))))
main = print $ leftAssociate ex1
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR:

instead of turning:

```
             +
            / \
           /   \
          a     +
               / \
              /   \
             b     c
```

into

```
             +
            / \
           /   \
          +     c
         / \
        /   \
       a     b
```

I'd suggest to alter the tree to be non-binary:

```
          +
         /|\
        / | \
       a  b  c
```

## Longer Explanation

> if we have `a + (b + c)` the function has to return `(a + b) + c`

I would not do that. I would choose a different representation than `Expr = Val Int | App Op Expr Expr`. `Expr` as binary tree is not associative. How about

```
data AssocExpr = AVal Int | AApp Op [Expr]
```

Lists are associative by design. You can keep both data structures around and convert to `AssocExpr` when you need the associativity. And if you really need it, you can still convert back and thereby achieve the initial goal.

To transform from `Expr` to `AssocExpr`, you can modify `leftAssociate` from K. A. Buhr's answer and eliminate the `foldl1`:

```
associate :: Expr -> AssocExpr
associate a@(App op _ _)
  | isAssoc op = AApp op $ opTerms a
...
```

Related Codereview (from myself):
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254288/parametrize-by-type-constructor/254572#254572